# Prove that there exists N ∈ (N) such that $a_n$ > 0 for all n ≥ N.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, proof-writing

Let $(a_n)$ be a convergent sequence. Suppose that $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ $a_n$ > 0. Use the definition of a
limit to prove that there exists N ∈ (N) (naturals) such that $a_n$ > 0 for all n ≥ N.

Use definition of a limit ($|a_n-L|$<$\epsilon$) and definition of convergence of sequences.

I have no idea how to even start this proof, or what I should be doing with it. I know I'm trying to solve that $a_n$ > 0, but I don't know how to get there. Not looking for a full proof, just some help of what I should be doing, what I should choose N to be, etc.

Comment: Let $L$ be the limit of your sequence. Then $L > 0$ by hypothesis. Now the definition of limits tells you that for all $\epsilon > 0$ after a certain rank $N$, $a_n$ is distant from $l$ for at most $\epsilon$. What happens for $\epsilon = L/2$ ?

Comment: Here's a suggestion. Call the limit L, so that L>0. The definition of limit tells you that given any $\epsilon$ there's an N such that if $n\geq N$ then $|a_n-L|<\epsilon$. That's what will produce this N that you are looking for. What you need to do is to choose an $\epsilon$ so that $|a_n-L|<\epsilon$ will force $a_n>0$. Try drawing a picture.

Comment: You write, "Use definition of a limit ($|a_n-L|$<$\epsilon$) and definition of convergence of sequences." This suggests some confusion and also that you are very new to the study of convergent sequences. My suggestion would be to write down the definition of "limit of a sequence". Note that if a sequence is convergent, then it converges to a limit. In other words, the definition of "a sequence converges" is the same as "a sequence has a limit". There are not two different concepts going here, just one.

Comment: @AdamRubinson I am really new to it, but my professor told us explicitly to use definition of a limit AND convergence of sequences, so I think that's what is throwing me off, cause it sounds like it should be more complicated than just with definition of a limit.

Comment: Ok well then, you need to tell us exactly what the definitions of "limit of a sequence" and "convergence of sequences" your professor has given you to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $L:=\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n >0$ and set $\varepsilon =\frac{L}{2}$: then by definition of limit we know there exists $N$ such that $|a_n-L|<\varepsilon$ for all $n>N$ - conclude from here that $a_n>0$ for all $n>N$-

Comment: Upvoted. I don't know why this answer got downvoted: it looks correct to me.

Comment: @AdamRubinson thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Taking $\epsilon = a = \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$, we know there is $N$ such that for $n \geq N$ we have $|a_n - a| < a$ hence $-a < a_n - a < a$ and $0 < a_n < 2a$. In particular, $a_n > 0$ for $n$ large enough.